# Performance issues with Spring Boot 2.x?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, tomcat

I recently updated the version of Spring Boot used in a web application from version 1.5 to 2.1.  When I ran the load tests against it, my run times went from 25 minutes to 35 minutes.

I know it is a broad question, but does anyone have any clues as to why the application would slow down so dramatically after upgrading the Spring Boot libraries?

EDIT:  After spending a lot of time trying to understand profiler ouput, The  problem appears to be in the communication to the database.  The Mariadb JDBC driver calls java.io.FilterInputStream.read to get data back from the database. According to the profiler, the application spends nearly twice as long in this method when running in Spring Boot 2 as it did in Spring Boot 1 (using Hikari for both).  Same application.  Same Database.  Same mariadb drivers.  Only the version of Spring changed, and whatever Spring brought in (like tomcat 9 instead of 8, or hibernate 5.3 instead of hibernate 5.0)

EDIT #2: I've done some more testing.  I ran Spring Boot 2.1 with a downgraded Tomcat (8.5.37), and the performance remained bad, so it would seem that Tomcat is not the issue.  Next, I ran Spring Boot 1.5 with an upgraded Hibernate (5.3.10), and performance remained good, so it would seem that Hibernate isn't the issue either.  That doesn't leave much other than spring boot itself, and it remains a complete mystery to me why a class in java.io would take longer under one framework than another.

This is preventing me from moving forward Spring Boot updates to production, so I appreciate any pointers you have,

Steve

Comment: What properties are being set? How complex is the code? What’s the backend? There are a myriad of things that could cause this

Comment: 25 minutes of test is already huge. Only full integration tests should spend so much time.

Comment: They are full integration tests designed to show how the application performs with thousands of users, which is why it takes a while to run.

It is a Spring MVC project using Tiles and JSP pages for the front end.  I wouldn't consider it a particularly complex application, so I was pretty surprised when the performance test degraded by that much.

Are there any particular properties I should check?  Especially things that changed from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2.1?

Answer (score 1):

Performance regressions may come from a lot of causes. So I suggest to include the [javamelody-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/SpringBootStarter) in your application.

That way you may find the performance regressions among the longest http or sql requests.

And perhaps more important, you may find which http and sql requests should be improved for overall performance, according to statistics during load tests or in production.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out JavaMelody.  I hadn't heard of it before.

The results I saw were interesting.  It showed that most numbers were better in Spring Boot 2 than Spring Boot 1.  Queries were faster, service methods were faster, but the overall performance was slower.  The only number JavaMelody marked as higher in Spring Boot 2 was in JSP rendering. Do you know of any ways to make JSPs faster?

I'm not sure if JSPs alone explain the slowdown I'm seeing. Is there something else I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the perfect answer.

But just an observation: Spring boot 2(2.1.4 to 2.1.7) definitely has performance issues if compared against version 1(1.59).

We ran JMeter tests for 8 hrs, hitting 100-150 tps, which sustained the load in both the versions, but average response time increased by almost 50-70ms and lots of spikes were there.

The versions lower than 2.1.4(**2.1.3** has slightly better performance but not the best.

1 >> 2.1.3 > 2.1.7