# SpringBoot SpringIntegration TomcatServlet How can I have more threads (than 1) for my incoming HTTP requests?

Tags: spring-boot, http, servlets, spring-integration

I've got a simple restful api in SpringIntegration 5.5.15, SpringBoot 2.7.6 and SpringFramework 5.3.24.

It's using a `http:inbound-gateway` to map the incoming requests to the channels in the workflow, making calls out via `http:outbound-gateway` to external restful APIs.

I get the impression that I'm not getting much parallelism in this API, that only a single API call at a time is being serviced (out of 200 simultaneous calls) and I'm not sure where the limitation lies.  I've tried adding an executor to the channel referenced by the `http:inbound-gateway` via the `request-channel` but that doesn't seem to even work as it doesn't wait for the downstream response.

I must be missing something fundamental.  Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have a `QueueChannel` in your flow which you don't mention in this question. `PollableChannel`s are consumed via scheduled tasks and default thread pool for an auto-configured `TaskScheduler` is really `1`.

See this SO thread: [Performance issue with upgrade of spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70973617/performance-issue-with-upgrade-of-spring-boot)

and this doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.task-execution-and-scheduling

Comment: Following your suggestion, I've tried setting ```spring.task.scheduling.pool.size``` to something big (200) but no change.  I'm not sure about having a ```QueueChannel``` because I have not set one up directly, but there is a ```splitter``` with an ```aggregator``` using the standard ```SimpleSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy``` which perhaps sets up a ```QueueChannel``` or introduces a different task limitation.

Comment: You can add a  Message History  into your your configuration then enable `DEBUG` logging for `org.springframework.integration` to see how your messages are traveling and in what threads. Perhaps when you aggregate, you lose headers from request, especially a `replyChannel` headers on which that `http:inbound-gateway` is waiting for reply. No, an aggregator does not create a queue, but it indeed waits until release condition is sutisfied, but this is done in an async manner: it does not block the current thread waiting.

Comment: I've tried that .. assuming that, for ```tomcat```, the executing thread is ```http-nio-XXXX-exec-YYYY``` where ```XXXX``` is the port number and ```YYY``` is the thread number.  I am seeing some high numbers for ```YYY``` so I'm guessing that I am getting multiple threads.  That seems to answer my question, so thanks for the help.